# Triangles in a line HTML/CSS web design

Tags: html, website, css, webpage, shapes

I'm currently designing a website for a class and I am having difficulty figuring out how to line up the triangles to form a diamond.

Thank you for your help all.

Here's the page:

[image: Web Page]

Here's the CODE:

[image: HTML code]

[image: CSS code pg1]

[image: CSS code pg2]

[image: CSS code pg3]

Comment: Hi Ahkil, you might want to put the code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use SVG rather than HTML elements if possible. if you MUST use html elements you could do something like the following:

```
.diamond {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}
.diamond:after {
  content:'';
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  top:-50px;
  left:50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
```

used with html:

```
<div class="diamond"></div>
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVKwaw)

Answer (score -1):

**Follow the Examples**
**Add HTML:**

Right arrow:

Left arrow:

Up arrow:

Down arrow:

**Add CSS:**

.arrow {
border: solid black;
border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px;
}

.right {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
transform: rotate(135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
transform: rotate(-135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

Comment: Firstly, this looks like it was copied verbatim from  [`How TO - CSS Arrows`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_arrows.asp). Secondly, I can't see how this answers the OP's question.